# wsdlpull: linking error with g++

Tags: c++, g++

I'm new to programming c++ with g++ and have big problems to get `wsdlpull-library` to work. The version is 1.24.

I followed the installation steps from http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/.:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/jesse/Dropbox/Programmering/C++/test --disable-opt --enable-examples
make
make install
```

I then copied `print.cpp` file from the example to the "prefix"-directory.  The next step would be "add the `$(prefix)/include` in your include path and add `$(prefix)/libs` and `-lwsdl -lschema -lxmlpull` to your `LDFLAGS`". The first problem is that there's no folder "libs" but "lib" and the include-folder has another folder inside named `wsdlpull`. Therefore I instead entered the following command:

```
g++ -I include/wsdlpull -L lib -lwsdl -lschema -lxmlpull -o print print.cpp
```

This resulted in the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwsdl
>       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lschema
>       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxmlpull
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have no idea what this means, why does it look in /usr/bin/ld when I point to "lib"?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-L lib`, it means that, `lib` dir is available in `pwd` where you are doing `make`. Check whether you have said `lib` is really available or not.

To make things simple, you can give the absolute path of the `lib` folder.
i.e `-L<path to lib>/lib`. This would help the `make` to see the `lib` without any confusions.

Next, you might want to explicitly specify whether `libwsdl` is a static or shared library. Although this is optional.

Or, the best solution is to place the libraries in system libs location i.e `/lib or /usr/lib or /use/local/lib` and run `ldconfig` such that the linker/loader knows where the newly added libraries exists. In such case, you can simple issue `-lwsdl` without specifying the `-L` flag.

For more info, please refer [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

Comment: I tried to give the -L<path to lib>/lib but it won't work. I might think there is something wrong with the tutorial because isn't the library naming convention that if e.g. I have a libwsdl.so file then I write -lwsdl in the command (remove prefix and suffix)? But I don't have that file, instead the name is "libwsdlpull.so" and so on. I therefore instead tried "g++ -I include/wsdlpull -o print print.cpp -L /home/jesse/Dropbox/Programmering/C++/test/lib -lwsdlpull -lwsdlpullschema -lwsdlpullxml" which works to compile but not to run  ("error while loading shared libraries: libwsdlpull.so.1")

Comment: Okay. What is the `SONAME` of `libwsdlpull.so` ? You can get the SONAME using objdump. objdump -p <libname> | grep SONAME

Comment: the SONAME of libwsdlpull.so is libwsdlpull.so.1 and the SONAME of that is also libwsdlpull.so.1

Comment: Hmm. What is the output of ls -l `libwsdlpull.so` ? Did it points to `libwsdlpull.so.1` ?

Comment: While loading / linking the shared lib, the linker will always see the SONAME. Your lib name is `libwsdlpull.so`, however it's `SONAME` is `libwsdlpull.so.1`. Hence the problem. There is a mistake in `libwsdlpull.so` build. Normally there will be versioning info on the lib name, but not on the `SONAME`. Did you build the `libwsdlpull.so.1` yourself?

Comment: I ran ls -l libwsdlpull.so and that points to libwsdlpull.so.1.0.24.  I have not made any files myself, the *.so, *.so.1, *.so.1.0.24 is built after running make